# Python2.7 Modules Missing

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to work with Python 2.7 in eclipse on my Mac, I don't belive that I have ever messed with the source files, but when I try to import urllib, urllib2 or random it tells me that it can't find them. I used the eclipse autoconfig-ed 2.7 interpreter so I have no idea what happened to the modules. How can I find it so that I can include it?

Comment: Are you running the scripts in eclipse?  Are you using pydev? In the preferences, PyDev>Interpreter - Python, do you have an interpreter set?

Comment: Yes, like I said in the question, though it may have not been clear, I am using PyDev and I'm using the autoconfig to create it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check that Eclipse has the right PYTHONPATH environmental variables.  Open a python interactive interpreter in a shell and try importing the same urllib, urllib2 and random modules.  If that works, then Eclipse might be configured wrong.  If you can't access those modules, then you should consider fixing your PYTHONPATH.

Comment: Ok, you were spot on with checking the python interactive. It can see random in python 2.7.2 but how to I adjust my PYTHONPATH in eclipse?